Reading a file from the download directory
I am trying to read an Excel file from the download directory on my phone.
I know the name of the file and it is in the download directory.  I can read the file in my app if the file is stored in the app specific "file" directory but I want to be able to read from the download directory without using a file picker.  Since I know the file name I want to be able to read it directly.
Here is my sample code:
package com.example.reading_excel

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.PermissionChecker
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.IOException

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
fun readExcelFile(context: Context, fileName: String) {
   // Check for permission if necessary (Android 13 and below)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT \<= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,      Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED
) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Permission needed to access files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    return
}

    // Define the file path in the Download directory
    val downloadDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val excelFile = File(downloadDirectory, fileName)
    
    if (!excelFile.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "File not found in Downloads", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }
    
    // Open the Excel file
    try {
        FileInputStream(excelFile).use { fileInputStream ->
            val workbook = XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream)
            val sheet1 = workbook.getSheet("Handicap Index & Course Play...")
            for ( i in 1..numPlayers) {
                PlayerData[i].name = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(2).stringCellValue
            }
            workbook.close()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error reading Excel file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}

Now the code is doing what I expect until I get to the line
   FileInputStream(excelFile).use { fileInputStream ->

which is failing because of an EACCESS error on trying to read the file.
The key here is the error is not on locating the file but rather opening it is causing the permissions error.  So it is a permissions problem but I am not sure where or how to change the permissions.  I do have
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

This question is similar to: Open a Downloaded file (pdf) from the Downloads folder in the INTERNAL STORAGE. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't see a it as distinctly different but this answer does not really explain how the permissions are handled.  I can read a file using a filepicker but that seems to be handling the permissions somewhere in the background.  I don't need a file picker because I know the location and name of the file..  It has to be in external storage because it gets updated everyday and it is not easy to copy it to app inteenak storage.

To my understanding the File Picker/SAF is for a one-time end-user file selection as opposed to locating a file you can repeated access, see:java.lang.SecurityException on takePersistableUriPermission() (SAF) If you want to access the file without user action, you'll have to either copy it to your app's internal storage and/or have the app download from original source as frequently as required from your app.

In Android 10+, scoped storage restricts general access to shared directories which includes "download" directory. You can use app specific external directory access (Android/data/) instead. If access to download directory without user action is absolutely necessary for your app, you'll need All Files Access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission. But Google Play requires apps to have a justifiable reason for requesting All Files Access. Otherwise your app will be rejected
